# Use none gulp plugins with gulp

Tags: gulp

I need to generate my css to json.
I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssparser) plugin but I don't know how to use it with gulp

```
gulp.task("lesstojson", function() {
    gulp.src("style.less")
        .pipe(less())
        .on("error", console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 2 versions', 'ie'], {cascade: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("css"))
        .pipe(cssparser());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/cwdoh/cssparser.js/tree/6d61b6af6cb69ef45dd8d7d32102c20698a8ec62#from-commonjs-module) of the module you found, cssparser does not support piping in CSS, which is what you are trying to do in the snippet you posted. Instead, you need to pass it your CSS as an argument; this might look like this:

```js
gulp.task('lesstojson', function() {
  gulp.src('style.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 2 versions', 'ie'], {cascade: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));

  var parser = new cssparser.Parser();
  var json = parser.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'css', 'style.css')));
});
```